# Open basefragment from activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

How can I open fragment from activity on android app. I tried to do this, but fragment didn't open:

```
        BaseFragment manager = new SurveysFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.test_l, manager)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.test_1, fragment).commit();
    }
```

and call this function like this

```
openFragment(new BaseFragment());
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't work. Becouse I need to use BaseFragment, and not Fragment . If I do it, I have error in  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: Make sure that you use android.app.v4.FragmentManager  and fragment in which fragment you are using

Comment: I did it:
openFragment(new SurveysFragment());public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.test_l, fragment).commit();
    } but I got error BaseFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Answer (score 0):

> When you want to open BaseFragment than why you are making instance of
>   surveysFragment it holds surveyFragment instance to BaseFragment
>   reference so change it like below and note check your BaseFragment
>   that extended Fragment must be android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,
>   for this you can check the import of Fragment inside your
>   BaseFragment.

```
 BaseFragment manager = new BaseFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.test_l, manager)
                .commit();
```